# How to search emails by matching header fields against regex "in" Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, regex, file-search

How to search emails by header fields such as Subject, Sender, Receipt, against regex? The emails are fetched and read with Thunderbird. But the searching doesn't need to occur through Thunderbird interface.

1) I need a solution to IMAP email account.

2) I don't want to install other email clients such as Mutt.

3) I am open to solutions that needs programming in Bash, Perl, Python, and ideally not others.

4) Ideally, I want to find some addon for doing multi-field and regex based searching.

5) After finding the emails, I typically want to visually determine a few interesting ones and read their content.

[EDIT] Added 1).
[EDIT] Added 5).

Comment: The account to be searched is an IMAP or local/POP3 account?

Comment: This is an IMAP account. If a reasonably coherent solution exist for both POP3 and IMAP, it will be even better.

Comment: Once the search is complete, what action do you want to take?  My question is - is this an interactive type search, or something that would be done in the background, like a scheduede task that moves/deletes/etc files that meet a set of criteria (and if so, what OS are we using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Expression Search extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gmailui/) for Thunderbird